# Encoding UTF-8 in Rails form parameter name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm having a problem with my params.
I'm receiving the following parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=", "Portugu\xC3\xAAs"=>{"title"=>"313" } }
```

In my controller I need to use the key => "Portugu\xC3\xAAs", but first I need it to be in the right form (that is -> Português) and I don't know how can I do that.

EDIT:

Workflow
1. The user saves a language
2. I use that language in a form to save information, like this:

```
Português[title]
```

3 . Because the user can have multiple locales in that form (all the locales saved in step 1)

```
locales.each do |locale|
 ...
 :value => params[locale.key][:title]
```

The problem is that locale.key ('Português') doesn't match with "Portugu\xC3\xAAs" so it crashes with nil

Can you help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Need more details... In what way are you sending the parameters to the backend in the first place?

Comment: You can always leave the param name without accents. It is a bad practice to make variable/attribute names with accents.

Comment: I think it's usable like that. Try to display it in a view to see what it gives

Comment: I added more information, hope it helps

Comment: What rails and ruby version are you using, it is important for encoding questions

Comment: ruby is ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) and rails is rails 3.0.3

Comment: That's strange. On ruby 1.9 `"Português" == "Portugu\xC3\xAAs"` returns `true` (which it should).

Comment: Hum i can't even do that in the console, how do you do "Português" in the console? for me it gives "Portugu\U+FFC3\U+FFAAs" (even copy/paste)

Comment: Try running your console in UTF-8: `rails console -- -E UTF-8`. See if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this, and the result is good:

```
    <% p = {}
       p["Português"] = {}
       p["Português"][:title] = "Title in Portugês" %>
    <p><%= p["Portugu\xC3\xAAs"][:title] %>
```

And I get

```
<p>Title in Portugês</p>
```

I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was iterating the received params and with the help of URI.escape compare the string, if matches enc_locale is set and used in the value.
Thanks to everyone that helped!

```
    enc_locale = ""
    params.each do |param|
      if URI.escape(param[0]) == URI.escape(locale.key)
        enc_locale = param[0]
      end
    end

   ...
   :value => params[enc_locale][:title]
```